# Double redirection call?

Tags: python, callback

I have a **name** of obj attribute stored in a string and want to call the function/method stored in attribute with that **name**.

Is this the correct way of doing it :

```
        res = getattr(self, attr_name_str)()
```

I have to build alot of other code before I can test this syntax.
And wanted to know if is possible

Comment: Probably. When you tried it, what happened? We need a working example to say for sure.

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: But can't you just simply test it on anything? It shouldn't take long, maybe even less than writing this question.

Answer (score 1):

That can work. *I have to build alot of other code before I can test this syntax.* - But you don't. A very nice thing about python is that it is easy to experiment. Just crack open the shell and try it

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def bar(self):
...             return "I am bar"
...     def test(self, attr_name_str):
...             res = getattr(self, attr_name_str)()
...             print(res)
... 
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.test("bar")
I am bar
```

checked.